# F# pattern matching on discriminated union containing records

Tags: f#, pattern-matching, record, discriminated-union

I am trying to create a simple scenario; where a discriminated union has records as members. Getting an error "pattern discriminator not defined" while trying to do a pattern match in a simple function.

```
type Circle =
  {
  radius : float
  }

type Rectangle =
  {
  width : float
  height : float
  }

type Shape =
  | ACircle of Circle
  | ARectangle of Rectangle


let calcualteArea shape =
   match shape with 
   | Circle(radius) -> System.Math.PI*radius*radius  // error: pattern discriminator not defined
   | Rectangle(width, height) -> width*height
```

Please help me resolve the error.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax is different than you're expecting in two ways. First, you should match on `ACircle` and `ARectangle`, since those are the names of the cases of your `Shape` type. A discriminated union case name is different from a type name. Second, the syntax for pattern matching a record looks like this:*

```ml
type Rectangle =
    { width: int
      height: int }

let area rectangle =
    match rectangle with
    | { width = width; height = height } -> width * height
```

Given this, your function should look like this:

```ml
let calculateArea shape =
    match shape with 
    | ACircle({ radius = radius }) -> System.Math.PI*radius*radius  // error: pattern discriminator not defined
    | ARectangle({ width = width; height = height }) -> width*height
```

* Note that the pattern matching here is strictly optional; you *can* just as easily use `| ARectangle(rectangle) -> rectangle.width * rectangle.height` to access the fields.